# LINQ Where causing 'Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 65676'

Tags: c#, linq

So I recently update my entity model from the db to reflect some changes to various columns. I believe the only changes were making some "smallint" into regular int.

Now when I run these following lines, I get the 'Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 65676' error, but the problem is I never got it before, and I'm just gathering a bunch of entries, so where is the math even involved that would cause this issue?

```
var gameTeamKeys = gameTeams.Select(i => i.GameTeamKey).ToList();
var foundGameTeamPlayers = db.GameTeamPlayers.AsNoTracking().Where(i => i.IsActive == 1 && i.IsDeleted == 0 && gameTeamKeys.Contains(i.GameTeamKey.Value)).ToList();
gameTeamPlayers.AddRange(foundGameTeamPlayers);
```

The 2nd line is where the error is thrown. I'm not sure what LINQ is doing behind the scenes to cause this to fail now, everything I hover over in VS says int (although I don't know if it would say different if int16, but again, it worked before).

Here is the actual error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader

The overflow error was the Inner Exception, if that helps.

Why would this fail and how would I fix it?

**Additional info:**

When I run this query in Management Studio I get 75678 results, which is clearly above the limit for small int, however I don't know how that would apply when it worked before and the list is of an object type, there are no sums or anything.

Comment: Do `GameTeamKey` and `GameTeamKey.Value` have the same type?

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo almost definitely not. But nothing that we can infer for certain with the code provided.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo GameTeamKey are both int in MS SQL data types, although one is nullable (in gameTeamPlayers table). Double checking the .edmx file, they are both Int32

Comment: Do you have any `smallint` fields in the edmx file?

Comment: @NetMage yeah there are some in other fields in both tables, however they were there before when it worked.